# QGIS: Batch processing interface won't separate input files into distinct rows

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, whitebox-tools

I'm trying to analyze a folder-full of las files using functions in Whitebox Tools. I have no problem analyzing individual files; the issue has to deal with batch processing.
When I right click the tool in the processing toolbox and select >1 input file, the batch processing dialog concatenates the inputs into a single row, separating each with a ";" rather than breaking them out into separate rows. This causes the tool to fail, as it expects a single input.

This behavior is consistent for all the WBT tools, as well as graphical models I've created incorporating WBT tools. Note that the tools work fine on single input or if I manually add rows in the batch dialog using the '+' icon -- it's just specifying multiple inputs to the batch processing that is the problem. Also, it's not a behavior I see with other tools in different toolboxes (i.e., they populate distinct rows rather than concatenating inputs).

I could manually hit "+" and specify each file, but I have hundreds...

[image: example of what I see]

I'm using QGIS version 3.4.0-Madeira and the latest version of WBT from https://github.com/jblindsay/whitebox-tools#4-available-tools

Comment: I have the same behavior on 3.4.6. On the 3.6. * and 3.7 I can select only one file. It seems to by some qgis issues because the same behavior is in "File/folder Input" in processing.  [QGIS bug tracker](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21859)